# MarkLogic - Wildcard searches does not return results

Tags: search, wildcard, marklogic

We have implemented API thru xquery using search:search.

While searching for "Skill/matrix", it returns data.

When we search for Skill?matrix OR *ill/matrix, it returns zero records or sometimes throw exception with time exceeded.

Other wild card searches are working fine like
convert?r*1 OR invert?r* OR rectifi?r* OR changer* OR transvert?r*

Wild card option at Database & "Word Query" leve are set to true

- trailing wildcard searches
- trailing wildcard word positions

So not sure how to debug and solve this issue?

Comment: As a debugging step, pass your search string to `search:parse` and inspect the `cts:query` output. This should allow you to determine whether the problem is in parsing the query string, or if it's an index configuration problem.

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard search is not grep. A wildcard character will substitute for characters within the same word. So `Skill?matrix` is looking to match a single word with a letter between `Skill` and `matrix`, but there is no such word in `Skill/matrix` because that is a phrase involving two words with punctuation in between. You could instead do a punctuation and whitespace insensitive search for the phrase 'Skill matrix' and it would match and be much more efficient.

The `*ill/matrix` should match, but depending on your index and query settings it may be attempting to do a full match of `*ill` against the word lexicon or if you have no word lexicon it may be attempting to do a filtered scan of the whole database. See what your query plan is (`xdmp:plan`). If you have the three character index and pass an explicit `lexicon-expand=off` option to the query it will run faster. Just having trailing wildcards enabled but attempting to do leading wildcards is not going to work well.

Or, if you want to treat wildcards like grep, and this is not general search for phrases in running text, but more like code word lookup in a short element, you may be better off putting a string range index on that element and using you patterns to match against that range index instead.